# Beef installation package 'libgcc-9-dev' has no installation candidate, Unable to locate package gcc-9-base

Tags: beef

I am getting the error in the image while uploading. I tried some solutions on the site but it didn't work. what should I do

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdp0e.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is being fixed: see https://github.com/beefproject/beef/pull/2250

Comment: problem solved, thanks.